# How to catch parameters ajax in Codeigniter?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, get, xmlhttprequest

I attempted AJAX in CodeIgniter for the first time. This all went successfully until I found out that I wasn't retrieving any set parameters. Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

View: http://pastie.org/3727011

Controller: http://pastie.org/3727014

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajaxcontrolleur", true);
xmlhttp.send("q="+str);
```

Comment: when I try it I have a error message like that in firebug console :<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /CodeIgniteLien/ajaxcontrolleur was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/CodeIgniteLien/ajaxcontrolleur"